# Datepickr Javascript changing input value

Tags: javascript, input, datepicker

I'm struggling to work out this code.  I am using [datepickr](https://code.google.com/p/datepickr/), but happy to use any datepicker.  I have an HTML form that inputs its values into a document management system.  What I need is the input value to be replaced so that the date and date format are placed back in in this format '2014-06-11 00:00:00.000'.  In Datepickr's orignal form it seems not to update the value of the input field, it only fills in the input box so can't pass the value.  Here is my code:

HTML

```
<INPUT CLASS="valueEditable" Type="text" id="_1_1_2_1" name="_1_1_2_1" value="" size="10" required/>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var dp = new datepickr('_1_1_2_1', {
            'dateFormat': 'd/m/y'
        });

 dp.on('changeDate', function(ev){
   dp.val(ev.target.value);
});

});
```

Any help / suggestions very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the orginal Datepicker jquery UI :)

> ```
> $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
>   showOn: "button",
>   buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
>   buttonImageOnly: true
> });
> ```

ref:

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I can't get datepicker to work at all.  Even just with there demo code, it doesn't seem to work:

'  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepick" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepick"></p>
</body>'